# How to search for special `ResourceFunctions`

Tags: searching, resourcefunction

In Mathematica there exist several very useful Resource functions , for example  `ResourceFunction["MeanCurvature"]` and  `ResourceFunction["GaussianCurvature"]`, which I detected by accident .

Is it possible to search systematically for such functions?
For example a resource function which calculates the principal curvature?  (Unfortunately `ResourceFunction["PrincipalCurvature"]`  doesn't exist )

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the function [`ResourceSearch`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ResourceSearch.html).

Indeed, one can search for entries containing "curvature"

```
ResourceSearch["curvature"]
```

You then find that there exists a resource with the name ["PrincipleCurvatures"](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PrincipalCurvatures).

Comment: Thank you very much, that's the way!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Personally, I find it quite unfortunate that you cannot simply search the documentation for "principle curvature" and find what you want. But I guess we have to use the tools we're given.

Comment: Yes, my direct search  `ResourceFunction["PrincipalCurvature"]` could have earned a hint that   `ResourceFunction["PrincipalCurvatures"]` exists!

Comment: You can also find them all on the Wolfram Function Repository (including a search) https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/recent